# Different behaviour in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

This is my html file.

```
<BODY>
    <button id="b1" onclick="load()">Play</button>
    <canvas id="c1" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,1)">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="c2" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,2)">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="c3" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,3)">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <br>
    <canvas id="c4" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,4)">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="c5" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,5)">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <canvas id="c6" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,6)">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>

</body>
```

*This is my css file*

```
body{
    background - color: gray;
}
button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
canvas {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000000; display:none; }
```

**Expected result:** First 3 canvas elements in first row.
Next 3 canvas elements in second row.And gap between each canvas element is 20px.

**In Chrome:**
         I got the expected results for first row . But there is a collapse between second row elements. 
Firefox: I got the expected results for both rows.

Does anyone know why chrome behaves differently??

Comment: Try setting the margin and padding of your body to 0.

Comment: @Yiesra , I tried it . But it doesn't show any changes.

Comment: Try adding a property called box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: If i remove that <br> , i will get the result with padding.But i need a line break in that place.

Comment: @Yiesra , Sorry . It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
</br>
```

And instead, wrap your 2 sets of canvas inside divs, since they are display: block; the other group will be forced down, simulating what your br will be doing, except that it won't have the amount of space the 
 has.

```
<body>
<div id="set-one">
<button id="b1" onclick="load()">Play</button>
<canvas id="c1" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,1)">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<canvas id="c2" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,2)">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<canvas id="c3" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,3)">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</div>
<div id="set-two">
<canvas id="c4" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,4)">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<canvas id="c5" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,5)">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<canvas id="c6" onclick="f_clicked(this.id,6)">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
</div>
```

This way, you will have the 2 sets of canvas you want/need, most probably, without the space.